# @Retryable is not working with @EventListener Spring

Tags: java, spring, event-handling, spring-retry, spring-async

I have a method in class that is also a component. The method have the following annotations:

```
@Retryable(
    value = { Exception.class },
        maxAttempts = 2,
        backoff=@Backoff(delay = 2000))
@Async
@EventListener
```

For some resaon the retay is not being triggered.

Comment: did you add @EnableRetry config?

Comment: @Imran it solved the problem. Thank you.